# Precisely when and where was Feynman's Computer Heuristics lecture given?

Tags: reference-request

Feynman's Computer Heuristics lecture was apparently given at the Esalen Institute, Big Sur, California, in 1985.  But I have no formal evidence of this.  Has anyone ever cited [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA) that you can point out?

Comment: Talks are not usually cited.

Comment: The video has a date. I see no reason to mistrust it.